# TiddlyWiki 5: filter search result by suffix

Tags: filter, tiddlywiki5

Is there a way to filter search results (from quick search box) by tiddlers suffix?
For example, i want to search "Windows" and not see in result all the tiddlers ends up with .jpg: windows.jpg, etc.
Version is 5.1.13

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution that works for me:
edit  tiddler **$:/core/ui/DefaultSearchResultLis**
and add a filter for title results and content results. for example:

```
<$list filter="[!is[system]!suffix[.png]!suffix[.jpg]!suffix[.jpeg]!suffix[.PNG]!suffix[.JPG]!suffix[.JPEG]search:title{$(searchTiddler)$}sort[title]limit[250]]" template="$:/core/ui/ListItemTemplate"/>
```